# VS code snippets - what is the required number in front of a choice list?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, vscode-snippets

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_choice

```
${1|one,two,three|}
```

So I'm new to snippets, and I noticed the number in front of a list of completion choices is required to show the choice menu correctly (if omitted, it will populate the choice list as a literal string - https://github.com/infosec-intern/textmate-yara/pull/29).

What does this number do, and why is it needed ? 
(the documentation doesn't explain it)

is it for the default selection ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `${1|one,two,three|}` the `1` is a tabstop.  When you trigger the snippet that is the first place your cursor will go.  See https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_tabstops

> **Tabstops**
>
> With tabstops, you can make the editor cursor move inside a snippet.
>   Use `$1`, `$2` to specify cursor locations. The number is the order in
>   which tabstops will be visited, whereas `$0` denotes the final cursor
>   position. Multiple occurrences of the same tabstop are linked and
>   updated in sync.

Accorsing to the snippet grammar the tabstop number is required before a choice element.

`choice      ::= '${' int '|' text (',' text)* '|}'`

Since it is a choice element it makes sense that you want the cursor to go there at some time just by cycling through the tabstops with the <kbd>tab</kbd> key.  You can select the order of the tabstops, they don't have to be in any certain order within your snippet.  Tabstop `$2` could appear before `$1` for example.

And the tabstop has nothing to do with the default selection/option.  The default will always be the first option listed in the snippet.